# Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error...Swift3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3

I'm learning some swift 3 following courses on youtube.  The code below I've written is for creating a user account and storing details in a Firebase database.  When testing, I can progress up to the point of submitting the registration form.  I then receive the following error:

```
[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error.
Fatal Error: unexpectedly found nil whilst unwrapping an Optionional value.
```

I have also had the below on the line highlighted in the codeblock below:

```
exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)
```

Below is my code.  I have highlighted where the exception is thrown.  Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Signup_ViewController: UIViewController, 
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

// Input data fields for signup form
@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!

// Password data field for signup form
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordField: UITextField!

//  Next button for signup form (Hidden by default)
@IBOutlet weak var nextBtn: UIButton!

let picker = UIImagePickerController()
var userStorage: FIRStorageReference!
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    picker.delegate = self

    let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") // Defines URL for Firebase storage container

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    userStorage = storage.child("users") // Folder on Firebase storage
}

//  Image for signup form - user profile image
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

// Action for when user presses the "Select profile picture" button
@IBAction func selectProfileImagePress(_ sender: Any) {

    picker.allowsEditing = true // Enables user to edit photo
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary // Enables user to pick photo from photo library

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imgView.image = image // Checks image selected exists
        nextBtn.isHidden = false // Unhides "Next" button once image has been picked
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
// Action for when the "Next" button is pressed
@IBAction func nextPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard usernameField.text != "", nameField.text != "", emailField.text != "", passwordField.text != "", confirmPasswordField.text != "" else { return }
    if passwordField.text == confirmPasswordField.text {  // Checks password and confirm password match <---- Error highlights this line when the app crashes out.
           FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            if let user = user {

                let changeRequest = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.profileChangeRequest()
                changeRequest.displayName = self.nameField.text!
                changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: nil)

                let imageRef = self.userStorage.child("\(user.uid).jpg") // Creates JPG file for user uploading (user.uid is variable for specific user)

                let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgView.image!, 0.5) // Prepares user profile picture to be sent to Firebase.  Applies 0.5 compression to image.

                let uploadTask = imageRef.put(data!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print(err!.localizedDescription)
                    }

                    imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, er) in
                        if er != nil {
                            print(er!.localizedDescription)
                        }

                        if let url = url {
                            let userInfo: [String : Any] = ["uid" : user.uid,
                                                            "username" : self.usernameField.text!,
                                                            "name" : self.nameField.text!,
                                                            "urltoImage" : url.absoluteString]

                        self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(userInfo)

                            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userVC")

                            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    })
                })
                uploadTask.resume()
            }
           })

        } else {
        print ("Password does not match")
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that both passwordField and confirmPasswordField are correctly connected in the storyboard? This would explain the 'unexpectedly found nil' error on that line. I can't comment on the 'Creating an image...' Error - that is new to me.

Comment: hi, I've checked the confirmPasswordField, and even relinked.  Still get the error.  I have resolved the Creating an image error.

Comment: And the passwordField? Are you still getting the same unexpectedly found nil error on the same line? There are only two optionals on that line and one of them is nil - that is what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of your code :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
    self.imgView.image = image // Checks image selected exists
    nextBtn.isHidden = false // Unhides "Next" button once image has been picked
}
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

use this one ..

```
/// what app will do when user choose & complete the selection image :
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    /// chcek if you can return edited image that user choose it if user already edit it(crop it), return it as image
    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {

        /// if user update it and already got it , just return it to 'self.imgView.image'
        self.imgView.image = editedImage

        /// else if you could't find the edited image that means user select original image same is it without editing . 
    } else if let orginalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        /// if user update it and already got it , just return it to 'self.imgView.image'.
        self.imgView.image = orginalImage
    } 
        else { print ("error") }

    /// if the request successfully done just dismiss 
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

And for this error :

> Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error…Swift3

It's a bug in xcode , if picker could select and return images properly that means everything is okay , just ignore it .

Comment: Hi, this definitely resolved one of my problems.  Now I just have one more which I hope is resolved by the first posters comment.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice to see that. Dear, i already answer you ' "Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error " It's a bug in xcode , if picker could select and return images properly that means everything is okay , just ignore it .'